# Self-Referencing FK Generating Strangly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, auto-generate

In the screenshot below is an Entity (URL) in my model. The ParentId field is a self-referencing FK (points to Url.Id).  You can see this navigation at the bottom of the screenshot.

[image]

In my SQL and my DB, which I generate the EDMX from, the self-referencing FK is called FK_Urls_Parent:

```
-- Creating foreign key on [ParentId] in table 'Urls'
ALTER TABLE [Urls]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Urls_Parent]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId])
    REFERENCES [Urls]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

My questions are:

1. Why did EF generate Urls1 and Url1 just from that one FK?  Url1 is a 0 or 1 property that is 'FromRole' Urls1.  Urls1 is 'FromRole' Urls 'ToRole' Urls1.  It seems like EF is making a navigation property that is the exact same as Url table.  Why would it do this and can I do something to make it just generate the one, desired Navigation property: Urls1?
2. Okay, so not quite as important, but can I control the name of the Navigation property based on the FK name or something in the DB?  I hate that it names it 'Url1'.  I would prefer 'Parent', but don't want to have to manually change it in the designer every time I regenerate the model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is modeling both sides of the relationship. In other words, one of the properties will be the entry being pointed to by this entry's `ParentId`. The other will be the entry(s) whose `ParentId` field points to this entry.  You can disable one side in the relationship properties, or rename them to make sense. Such as, for instance, `ParentUrl` and `ChildUrls`.

I'm not 100% certain how to get to the property relation dialog without opening the program myself, which I can't right now. I do know for me it appears in the (by default) bottom-right properties window when the link is selected.

As far as making this change somehow permanent across model regenerations, I know of no way to do this. Hopefully someone else will know, because it would save me a lot of time too!

Comment: That would be ChildUrls since a single parent entity has a plurality of children.